# Dynamic generation of textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a javascript to generate textbox dynamically.

Code:

```
function addtextbox(val)
{
 var foo = document.getElementById('fooBar');
 var num = (document.getElementById('cnt').value -1 + 2);
 ingrds[num]= val;
 var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
 var divIdName = 'divid'+num;       
 newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="15" id="' + ingrds[num] + '" value="' +   val + '"><a href="javascript:remove('+divIdName+')">Remove</a>';
foo.appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

//function to remove dynamically added textbox

```
function remove(dId)
{
 var foo = document.getElementById('fooBar');
 foo.removeChild(dId);
}
```

Whenever remove function is called i want to get the value of the textbox before removing it. How to go about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where does `ingrds[num]` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function remove()
{
var foo = document.getElementById('fooBar');
var value = foo.value;
alert(value); // will show you the value for debugging purpose
foo.removeChild(dId);
}
```

input elements can have their value access using the `input.value` property.
The same goes for textarea element (textbox).

**EDIT**

```
"<a href="javascript:remove('+divIdName+')">Remove</a>"
```

can be changed to

```
"<a href="javascript:remove('+ingrds[num]+')">Remove</a>"
```

no your function ca use the parameter

```
function remove(id)
    {
    var foo = document.getElementById(id); // selects the input element
    var value = foo.value;
    foo.removeChild(dId);
    }
```

Comment: @lbu:foobar is a div. i have added many div as child node in it. The child node has textbox. i want to get the value of textbox of particular child node whose id is dId.

Comment: Thanks. But i am adding div while creating new textbox. hence your edited code is also not working.

Comment: still can work, pass 2 parameters then. `remove(divId,inputId)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use **[innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)**.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('fooBar');
var fooHtml = foo.innerHTML;
foo.removeChild(dId);
```

Comment: :fooHtml gives inner html of all the added textbox. I want of the particular child whose id i have passed in function remove.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the value. You're just selecting the element currently

```
function remove()
{
var foo = document.getElementById('fooBar').value;
foo.removeChild(dId);
}
```